# Key distribution and computation for homomorphic encryption

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation

How can a system where the party performing a computation also possess the private key and still not know the answer of computation be designed ? Also the other party who does not have the private key know the correct result ?

Involving a trusted third part seems a possible solution. But are there other ways to design such a system ?

Consider the following scenario: **A** has an input $x_1$, the public key and private key. **B** comes in with another input $x_2$. **A** sends the public key to **B**. **B** sends the encrypted value $enc(x_2)$ for **A** to perform a computation $C(enc(x_1), enc(x_2))$. **A** performs the computation and sends the result to **B**. **A** should not know the correct value of result. But here if **A** is performing the computation and also has the private key, then **A** can decipher the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, if you do things the way you describe, A would be able to decrypt B's private data. So don't do it that way.

Instead, since B is to know the answer, let B encrypt his private input with his **own** public key. He sends that to A. A encrypts her private input with **B's** public key, then runs the computation. A then returns the encrypted answer to B. B decrypts it.

Since you added [multiparty-computation](/questions/tagged/multiparty-computation), you may be interested in how this extends to more than two parties. Here is a relevant quote from [Craig Gentry's PhD thesis](http://crypto.stanford.edu/craig/craig-thesis.pdf)

> Extending our application of fully homomorphic encryption from the two-party setting to the multiparty setting is not entirely trivial, since, in the two-party setting, Bob prevented Alice from seeing any intermediate values encrypted under Alice’s key simply by finishing the computation himself, and sending back the final encrypted value to Alice; in the multiparty setting, it is less clear how one prevents Alice from seeing intermediate value encrypted under her key.

A number of protocols using homomorphic encryption to enable secure multiparty computation have been proposed, the most practical of which is probably [SPDZ](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/642).

Comment: If A is a database of values, then for each user B, A has to encrypt each of its value. So the computation party cannot have the private keys ?

Comment: @1010101 you are correct, though there are some tricks around this. Since FHE can evaluate any function, it can evaluate the AES decryption function. So, instead A can encrypt the database with AES, then encrypt the key with B's public key. B uses the encrypted key and the AES encrypted database to decrypt the database. The result of that decryption is not plaintext, however. It is the database encrypted with FHE.

Comment: You shouldn't really use AES in this case, there are some ciphers way more "FHE-friendly".

Comment: @Dillinur Could you suggest some ?

Comment: @Dillinur but do they have the security history of AES?

Comment: @mikeazo Well, FHE is still pretty new territory, so you'll have to make a trade-off when you choose your cipher. You'll lose some security but will have to do less operations for the decryption in FHE space, and thus you can use more effective computation operations with the same FHE overhead. You can of course roll with AES if your data size are small enough and/or if computational time is not a constraint.

Comment: @1010101 You could look at light-weight stream ciphers

Comment: If i get it correctly, the database is to be encrypted with AES or stream ciphers and then its decryption is to be carried out using FHE ?

Comment: @Dillinur very true.

Comment: @1010101 yes, you would likely encrypt database fields with some cipher. The decryption is carried out homomorphically. This is different from using the FHE decryption function.

Comment: So the computation with other value can be done after doing the homomorphically decrypted function ? The aim is to perform computation between a value by B and the values in database with A. Sorry, I am new to this and is getting confused.

Comment: @101010, yes, that is correct.

Comment: @1010101 don't forget, if you find this answer helpful you can up vote it and even accept it (click on the check).

Comment: I just came across this paper: [Ciphers for MPC and FHE](http://thomaschneider.de/papers/ARSTZ15.pdf)